# How to export 3D object in autocad 3D

Tags: 3d, autocad

I created 3D object in Autocad 3D.
The visual style (Realistic) when in autocad is perfect. However, when I export it into file .eps. 
This 3D object automatic change to 2D wireframe and missing some object??
All I want is export this object (with The visual style (Realistic)) into Word or Latex with high resolution.
I already try export it into .PNG and bitmap...
But the resolution is so bad. 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply not supported. It's difficult to translate such a rich view in polygons with a fixed number of polygon fill styles as EPS file format is all about.

Comment: Thank you. So the only option is export to png.